# Opcional a tipos de datos primitivos y String en test unitarios

Tags: c#, test

Hace un buen tiempo estuve haciendo una actividad sobre test unitarios en C#, no había ningún problema con las reglas que nos dieron, pero hubo una que me llamó mucho la atención y era el hecho de que no podíamos usar variables primitivas ni cadenas. Por una cuestión de tiempo omitimos este punto, pero cada caso de prueba que realizábamos lo hacíamos con números y textos, así que me quede con la curiosidad de cómo hacerlo.

La pregunta es:
**¿Hay algún otro camino para optar por no usar los tipos de datos primitivos y cadenas?**

En caso de que la respuesta sea afirmativa:
**¿Cuál/es son?**

Muchas gracias...

Comment: a que llamas "variables primitivas ni cadenas"? porque un texto es una cadena. Lo que describes no tiene ningun sentido, podrias pner un ejemplo en codigo de test que pueda ejemplificar lo que estas planteando

Comment: De eso se trata exactamente... un texto es una cadena... y en el ejercicio me decía que no puedo usar tipos de datos cadena ni primitivos...  la pregunta esta muy clara... si no los puedo usar, que otra opción tengo? porque el ejercicio era sobre un almacén, tenia que guardar info de una clase producto que contenía su nombre(cadena) y su stock(entero)

Comment: no entiendo, porque no lo puedes usar? es una limitacion sin sentido, definir un nombre es un texto (una cadena), no hay otra forma